# Search Box and Search Result not showing on Basic Page Layout

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, content-search-web-part

I created a page layout based the Basic Page Layout, after that I have added a web part zone and two webparts in it. One Search Box web part and another Search Result webpart. Strangely the first doesn't have an input and the second one, even having a results that are returned from the query doesn't show any element on the view. I am using the default item display template.

This site collection is of type Wiki and is on SharePoint Online. I have tried many combinations of properties along the page, the one I was closer is when I have set the input width and height manually it shown on the edit page, but once it goes to display page, nothing is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: 
I had a explicit call to `<script type="text/javascript" src="/layouts/sp.js"></script>` and to `sp.ribbon.js`. Hope this answer help somebody else.